# Adjacency matrix - r does not recognize my matrix

Tags: r, csv, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I wanted to create an adjacency matrix with a csv file but I'm getting the error described below.

It is a simple binary and undirected matrix which I want to convert into a graph; for example like this:

```
  A B C D 
A 0 0 1 1 
B 0 0 1 0 
C 1 1 0 0 
D 1 0 0 0
```

I'm trying using these R codes

```
library(igraph)
mydata <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE, row.names=1)
mymatrix <- as.matrix(mydata)
myfirstnetwork <- graph.adjacency(my_matrix,mode="undirected",diag=FALSE)
myfirstnetwork
plot(myfirstnetwork)
```

Unfortunately I got this error :

```
Error in graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted, :
At structure_generators.c:274 : Non-square matrix, Non-square matrix
```

After typing this it says:

```
head(mydata)
data frame with 0 columns and 6 rows.
```

I do not get this. It is a matrix with 23 columns and 23 rows. Can anyone help me?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an example of your data. Without an example dataset it will be more difficult to help. That being said I imagine it is probably an issue with the file you're reading in to my data.

Comment: @JeffreyBrabec please see below

Comment: @RaviSaroch unfortunately not but thanks! any other advices?

Comment: @Blackeagle Can you show how your csv file looks, please?

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine for me:

```
mymatrix <- apply(m, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1),1))
mymatrix
library(igraph)
myfirstnetwork <- 
graph.adjacency(mymyfirstnetworkmatrix,mode="undirected",diag=FALSE)
myfirstnetwork
plot(myfirstnetwork)
```

Resulted graph:

[image]

This error arise because your matrix does not have same number of columns and rows (square matrix). An adjacency matrix should be square.

Comment: Thank you very much for this @Ravi 
After a bit research I found out that the reason is that my .csv file uses semicolons as delimiters. Acutally it should use commas as delimiters. I think the reason is that I live in Germany and the computer language is german.

Comment: I just saw that my answer on your question was deleted from a moderator. My answer was: 
"It is a simple binary and undirected matrix which I want to convert into a graph; for example like this   
   A B C D 
A 0 0 1 1 
B 0 0 1 0 
C 1 1 0 0 
D 1 0 0 0